# How to show particular product in cms page?

Tags: magento2

I want to display specific product in CMS static page.
I want to create a .phtml file which displays particular product detail page based on the product id in cms page.
How can i do it.

Comment: {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="ENTER_YOUR_CAT_ID" product_count="12" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

Answer (score 0):

in your cms page write below code

```
{{block class="[Vendor]/[Module]/Block/Class" template="[Vendor]_[Module]::YourPhtml.phtml" }}
```